# Run Traefik container & whoami container on Docker Desktop but not able to get response from server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, traefik-ingress

I would like to have Traefik & `traefik/whoami` containers up and running.  Then access the `whoami` server via Traefik container.

I am using MacBook with M2 chip, that's armv8 architecture.  So, the image I use for "whoami" server is `traefik/whoami` which support armv8.

I run them in my local Docker Desktop environment.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    # The latest official supported Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.3
    # Enables the Traefik Dashboard and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    # --providers tell Traefik to connect to the Docker provider
    # enable --log.level=INFO so we can see what Traefik is doing in the log files
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker --log.level=INFO
    ports:
      # Exposes port 80 for incomming web requests
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI port http://0.0.0.0:8080 (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events e.g. container starting
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

# Add the whoami service
  whoami:
     # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
     image: traefik/whoami
     # We set a label to tell Traefik to assign a hostname to the new service
     labels:
       - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
```

As you can see above, in the `whoami` service, I have set a Traefik host rule, that `whoami.docker.localhost` should point to "whoami" server.

I run `docker-compose up -d`, there is no problem.  Both containers are up and running successfully.
[image]

Then, I open browser (Chrome) to access the host, no server response:
[image]

I also tried to access the Traefik dashboard http://localhost:8080, it is also can not be reached...

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the traefik logs?

Comment: I have copy pasted your compose file, and ran `docker compose -f "docker-compose.yaml" up`  and it just works. I can reach the mgmt api on localhost:80 and I can reach the whoami on whoami.docker.localhost. I am on windows 10 WSL2 Docker Desktop. So the problem is not in traefik or the docker-compose.yaml file but your mac/docker desktop setup.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing a few configuration options under "labels" in your whoami service - namely `traefik.enable` and `traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web`.

Taken from https://hub.docker.com/r/traefik/whoami:

```
  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

Comment: above code should fix your problem.

and for the dashboard problem, simply do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I've added `networks` for both the containers along with `hostname` for `whoami`. I'm using Windows but I'm sure this is going to work for everyone.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  portal-traefik:
    container_name: portal-traefik
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    image: traefik:latest
    networks:
      api_driven:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    container_name: whoami-traefik
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: traefik/whoami
    # We set a label to tell Traefik to assign a hostname to the new service
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`docker.internal.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web
    networks:
      api_driven:
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: docker.internal.localhost

networks:
  api_driven:
    name: "api_driven"
```

Output:

```
Hostname: docker.internal.localhost
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 192.168.240.2
RemoteAddr: 192.168.240.3:43628
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: docker.internal.localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7,pa;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.240.1
X-Forwarded-Host: docker.internal.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 16ca92e14aa2
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.240.1
```